# How to get rid of booby-trapped pop ups to update flash player?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, firefox, adobe-flash, malware

I'm coming across a malicious pop up to update my flash player. The message in the pop up:

```
Warning! Your Adobe Flash Player version is outdated. Security risks. Please update now.
```

[image]

I've seen this pop up across multiple browsers (chrome, safari, firefox) and occurs on all OSX machines on the local network. I've attempted to disable on plugins and extensions in chrome but the problem remains. Clicking ok takes me to a website that appears to be an official adobe website but the link to download the update is clearly wrong.
[image]

This problem just happened today across three machines simultaneously and I'm stumped as how to proceed. What's the best way to remove these pop ups?

Comment: This is a still burning question I asked a while ago: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/110456/22003 . I'm still waiting a decent answer. 3 millions dead accounts is a low starting point to build trust.

Comment: `fplayer.adobe.com` doesn't exist at Adobe and on the Internet. Could you please provide the output of the following `Terminal` commands:
`whois fplayer.adobe.com ;
 host fplayer.adobe.com`?

Comment: You'll also notice that the indicated system in your screen grab is "Windows 64-bit" which is impossible given that you're posting from Firefox on OS X.  This is a phishing attempt.

Comment: Could you find which common action you had on 3 Mac just before you got these phishing popups?
A same received E-mail, a same flash content to display, a same web server truck loaded of advertising…?

Comment: Each machine was used by a different person (mother and girlfriend) so I have no idea what we all did to get this. I think this may be a problem with my network or isp. The same popup shows up on iPhones when using the local wifi, but not when using data plans. I'm using an asus rt-n16 router for wifi behind an at&t u-verse modem. I can only change the dns on the router, and that doesn't fix it. Connecting directly to the modem doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: Output from terminal: https://gist.github.com/cezary/8186581

Comment: Seeing this as well past 3 days. Have reset router and forced everything to use Google DNS yet still see it acrosss many devices (Windows, iPhones, Xbox). At one point fplayer.adobe.com domain did exist and took me to a Russian download site with a fake Flash Player installer. Currently my network says that domain is non-existant bit I still get the popups being injected into most web requests somehow. Really worried what other traffic they're intercepting.

Comment: Router is an ASUS RT N56U. Reinstalled firmware yesterday but didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: How to inflect your router: http://www.acunetix.com/blog/web-security-zone/the-email-that-hacks-you/

Comment: I've never seen SE sites request flash, so you might have some real security problems in terms of hostile DNS, hostile web proxy or worse - modified software on all the Macs you have access to. Does your DNS even point to apple.stackexchange.com having an address of 198.252.206.16? You might need to compare the actual page source with someone on a clean browser/network to determine where the popup message is being injected.

Comment: @AllInOne that link describes exactly what's happening to me. I'm using an RT-N16, with a default password :(, but it seems the at&t gateway may have been infected as well.

Comment: Yes. I'm pretty security conscious myself but it never occurred to me that I could be vulnerable in this way. There are going to be a LOT more hacked routers now.

Comment: Doing `host apple.stackexchange.com` in the terminal returns `apple.stackexchange.com has address 198.252.206.16` So that seems to be working. At this point, I've contacted at&t and am going to try a new gateway.

Comment: → AllInOne: your comment is the right answer :).
Please make your comment an answer so as to bring a correct one to this serious security problem.

Answer (score 1):

When weird things happen on my clients' Macs, the first thing I do is run the free Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware (MBAM, formerly AdwareMedic software to see if any of the known "bad guys" is active on the system. As often as not, they are.

Also, have a look at your /etc/hosts file through Terminal:

1. Open Utilities > Terminal (or use Spotlight)
2. more /etc/hosts (press space bar to scroll a screen at a time)

See if fplayer.adobe.com is listed there. If so, we'll discuss how to remove it.

Try that and report back. Then we'll try step two.

Answer (score 0):

You are either visiting a website that is not credible or a system on the network has gotten a bad DNS so that it is talking with bad server and getting the pop-ups that way. Daniel's terminal commands are there to help figure out what your system points do with that domain thereby looking for the culprit.

Looking at the screenshot you attached something with location4.biz is the page hosting fplayer... Might need some intense triage on your systems for any unauthorised apps that have taken seed.

Hope this helps paint a picture....

Comment: This appears to be affecting iPhones using the local network as well, but not on their mobile connections. I've tried changing the dns server on each machine, on the router, connecting directly to the modem, resetting everything. Still seeing the same pop up.

Comment: Do the "infected" machines still show this when they access the internet from a different router?  Do machines that you know to not be infected appear to be infected when used on your network?  I suspect it is your *router* that is infected.

Comment: Is it possible for the problem to be with the 3801HGV router/modem at&t provides? I've bypassed my asus router and connected wirelessly and wired to it and still encounter the problem.

I contacted at&t and they recommended to power off the modem for 10 minutes to reset the ip. Still no dice.

Answer (score -1):

Removing all Safari's *.plist* files in `~/Library/Preferences` did the trick for removing the PopUp.

Comment: this is using a hammer for a job that calls for a spoon.

Answer (score -2):

Try delete your IP from OpenDNS if you are using this Open Source.